# Angular $http forces requests to remove www

Tags: angularjs, http, angular-http

I'm trying to send an Angular `$http` request to

```
https://www.myproject.com/users/123
```

Using

```
var usersURL = "https://www.myproject.com/users/" + "123";
            return {
                execute: function(){
                    return $http({
                        method: 'GET',
                        url: usersURL
                    });

                }
            };
        }
```

Yet, the console in Chrome says

GET http://myproject.com/users/123 net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

It seems the app is forcing the `https` to become `http` and removing `www` entirely.

Why is this happening? How do I stop this behaviour?

Comment: use relative url `var usersURL = "//www.myproject.com/users/" + "123";` this will help you

Comment: How could we tell you why your server responds with a 404 to this URL and what the correct URL should be? That depends on your server and on its database, and has nothing to do with angular. Why do you deduce from this 404 that you need to use http instead of https and remove www from the host name?

Comment: @JBNizet I am absolutely certain that the server requires `htts://www`. It's tested. The question is, why won't Angular send the request there?

Comment: It does send the request. Otherwise, how could you have a 404 response? You can't have a response without sending a request. Does the user 123 exist? What happens if you paste this URL in the address bar of the browser?

Comment: @JBNizet In the browser I get a JSON object with the data as expected

Comment: How could the chrome console say that you get a 404 for `http://www.myproject.com/users/123`if you send a request to the url `https://www.myproject.com/users/123`? You're probably not executing the code you think you're executing. Use the debugger to make sure you go through the code you posted.

Comment: @JBNizet You're right. I made a mistake with the message from Chrome. I've updated what Chrome is returning

Comment: That makes the question clearer. But I repeat, that probably means you're not executing the code you think you're executing. Put a breakpoint on the $http call, and see what the value of the URL is. The only explanation I can imagine is that you've somehow configured an http interceptor or decorator that changes the URL on the fly.

Comment: @JBNizet I did a console log just before the `$http` and it is exactly the URL I specified.